# Blazor (Server-Side) ErrorBoundary not working with EditForm

Tags: error-handling, blazor

ErrorBoundary exceptions not working with EditForm.

```
<EditForm Model="@netDocsMergeModel" OnSubmit="@(()=> MergeDocuments())">
```

...

```
private async void MergeDocuments()
{
    throw new Exception();

}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MyApp.Components.MyComponent/>
```

MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>MyApp</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            <ErrorBoundary>
                @Body
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Getting the regular Blazor unhandled exception message when doing this.

I also tried wrapping the EditForm directly and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

ErrorBoundary needs async Task to work. My oversight.

Hopefully this helps someone else

This fixed it.

Changing

```
private async void MergeDocuments()
{
    throw new Exception();

}
```

to

```
public async Task MergeDocuments()
{
   throw new Exception();
    
}
```